# Generalized Principal ideal theorem for ray class groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I 've seen the following statement in

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94480/generalization-of-hilbert-94-and-capitulation
and 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63465/where-does-the-principal-ideal-theorem-from-cft-go  .

"There is a generalization of the principal ideal theorem to ray class groups:

Let $K$ be a number field, $\frak{m}$ a modulus for $K$, $L:=K(\frak m)$ the ray class field modulo $\frak m$, and $\frak n$ the image of $\frak m$ in $L$. Then any element in the ray class group modulo $\frak m$ of $K$ becomes trivial in the ray class group modulo $\frak n$ of $L$.
The proof is almost identical to that of Principal ideal theorem, reducing to the same group theoretic statement."

How can I prove this?
In my thinking, it is required that $Gal(K({\frak{m}})/  K    )=Gal(L({\frak{n}})/K)^{ab}$ where $L(\frak n)$ is the ray class field modulo $\frak n$. But why does this hold?

Comment: @reuns I cannot write the full proof. Briefly, Emil Artin translated the principal ideal thm to the following group theory question: For a finite group $G$ such that $G'$ (the commutator subgroup of $G$) is abelian, $transfer map: G/G'=G^{ab} \longrightarrow G'$ is zero. It seems that this group theory question was proved by Furtwangler, and later by Iyanaga. I 've seen the proof in Neukirch's 'Algebraic number theory' Ch.6, Thm 7.5.

Comment: @ruins Your "$F/K$ has ramification data $\subset m$" means conductor, right? But I do not think that your claim holds...because if we let $\frak m$ $=p^r$, then $\frak n$ $=p^{re}$ where $e$ is the ramification index at $p$. If $e$ is sufficiently large, we cannot expect the asserted conductor condition...

Comment: $H = Gal(L(n)/K(m))$ then $G = Gal(L(n)/K) \to G/H$ factors through $G/[G,G]$ so you want to show the conductor of the abelian extension $F=L(n)^{[G,G]}/K$ divides $ m$ to obtain $F \subset K(m) $. If $L(n)/K$ is the splitting of the finite primes in $m$ ?

Comment: @ruins Surely splitting case satisfies the claim. Even more, If L/K is unramified, then principal ideal thm holds. Ramification index causes all problems....